# Prove $g(A \cap B) \subseteq g(A) \cap g(B)$ and $g^{-1}(A \cap B) = g^{-1}(A) \cap g^{-1}(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

If $g:\mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ and $A, B \subseteq \mathcal{R}$, then
\begin{align}
y \in g(A \cap B) &\rightarrow \exists x \in (A\cap B)~~s.t.~~ y=g(x) \tag{1}\\
& \rightarrow (\exists x \in A~~s.t.~~ y=g(x))~~ \land~~ (\exists x \in B~~s.t.~~ y=g(x)) \tag{2}\\
& \rightarrow y \in g(A) \land y \in g(B) \tag{3}\\
&\rightarrow y \in g(A) \cap g(B) \tag{4}
\end{align}

Two questions about the above proof:

1. Is the proof correct?
2. Why can we go from (1) to (2) seems like property that '$s.t.$' can be distributed over $\land$?

if $g^{-1}(B)=\{x \in \mathcal{R} : g(x) \in B\}$ where $B \subseteq \mathcal{R}$,then
\begin{align}
y \in g^{-1}(A \cap B) &\leftrightarrow \{x \in \mathcal{R} : g(x) \in A\cap B\} \tag{5} \\
&\leftrightarrow \{x \in \mathcal{R} : g(x) \in A\}~~ \land~~ \{x \in \mathcal{R} : g(x) \in B\} \tag{6} \\
&\leftrightarrow y \in g^{-1}(A)~~\land~~ y \in g^{-1}(B)\tag{7}\\
&\leftrightarrow y \in g^{-1}(A) \cap g^{-1}(B) \tag{8}
\end{align}

Again my questions are similar to above:

1. Is the proof correct?
2. Why can we go from (5) to (6)?
   Is there anything in logic that supports this?

Comment: Your first proof is correct.  The very same $x$ that "witnesses" that $y=g(x)$ for some $x \in A \cap B$ also works as a witness that $y=g(x)$ for some $x \in A$ and also for some $x \in B$.  Your second proof is unintelligible because it doesn't connect $x$ and $y$.  As a matter of notation I'd start with the assumption that $x \in g^{-1}(A \cap B)$, just because we usually use $x$ rather than $y$ as the argument of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your first proof is correct.  Here's how I'd write up the second proof:

Choose $x \in g^{-1}(A \cap B)$.  Then $y=g(x) \in A \cap B$.  In particular, $y \in A \land y \in B$, so since $g(x)=y$, we have $x \in g^{-1}(A) \land x \in g^{-1}(B)$, which means $x \in g^{-1}(A) \cap g^{-1}(B)$, proving $g^{-1}(A \cap B) \subseteq g^{-1}(A) \cap g^{-1}(B)$.

Conversely, assume $x \in g^{-1}(A) \cap g^{-1}(B)$.  Then $x \in g^{-1}(A) \land x \in g^{-1}(B)$.  This means $y = g(x) \in A \land y \in B$, so $y \in A \cap B$.  Since $g(x) = y$, we then have $x \in g^{-1}(A \cap B)$.  This proves $g^{-1}(A) \cap g^{-1}(B) \subseteq g^{-1}(A \cap B)$ and equality follows.

Comment: Thanks- you are right now looking back at the second proof and compare it with yours I see what the problem is.
Any ideas why we can go from (1) to (2) in the first proof? Seems like distribution of s.t. over the logical and. Is this true in general?

Comment: @abk I tried to explain in my comment to your question why your first proof is correct.  I don't think of it in terms of distribution.  I think of it in terms of finding a "witness."

Comment: Thanks- wondered if that can be proved in general for general cases.